# Are there different ways of declaring the controller associated with an Angular UI Router state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an interrogation about the Angular UI router.

Is it any different to declare the controller associated with the state at the **top level** or at the **view level**?

See snippet below:

```
.state('signup', {
    controller: 'SignupCtrl',//HERE
    views: {
        '@': {
            controller: 'SignupCtrl',//OR THERE
            templateUrl: 'signup/views/signup.html'
        }
    }
})
```

Is it any different to declare the controller `//HERE //OR THERE`?

If so what is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a big difference - because only one or the other is used. In fact, the most important message is:

> controller does **not** belong to `state`. It belongs to `view`!

In case if there is a `views : {}` object, each *view* can have its own `controller` defined.

```
.state('myState', {
    views: {
        '@': {
            controller: 'SignupCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'signup/views/signup.html'
        },
        'hint@': {
            controller: 'HintCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'signup/views/signup.html'
        }
    }
})
```

There is one exceptional views definition. It happens, if we target the ui-view="" in the state parent. In that case, we can still writ it like this:

```
.state('myState', {
    views: {
        '': {
            controller: 'SignupCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'signup/views/signup.html'
        },
    }
})
```

But we can use simplified version, equal to this definition:

```
.state('myState', {
    controller: 'SignupCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'signup/views/signup.html'
})
```

So last two are equal at the end. But again, in the last example we just used simplifed version. Controller always belong to view (template) not to state...

Comment: The point that "controller does not belong to state. It belongs to view!" helped!