# ui-router $stateProvider.state.controller don't work

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui, ng-controller

The `SignupCtrl` controller is not binding to signup view. Even when i press the submit button it don't work. But when i place ng-controller=SignupCtrl in the form tag it works. Just wondering why ui-router state parameter controller was not working.

index.html

```
<html class="no-js" ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <head> ....
  </head>
  <body class="home-page">
          <div ui-view="header"></div>
        <div ui-view="content"></div>
        <div ui-view="footer"></div>
...
```

signup.html

```
<div class="form-container col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <form class="signup-form">
    <div class="form-group email">
      <label class="sr-only" for="signup-email">Your email</label>
      <input id="signup-email" type="email" ng-model="user.email" class="form-control login-email" placeholder="Your email">
    </div>
    <!--//form-group-->
    <div class="form-group password">
      <label class="sr-only" for="signup-password">Your password</label>
      <input id="signup-password" type="password" ng-model="user.password" class="form-control login-password" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <!--//form-group-->
    <button type="submit" ng-click="createUser()" class="btn btn-block btn-cta-primary">Sign up</button>
    <p class="note">By signing up, you agree to our terms of services and privacy policy.</p>
    <p class="lead">Already have an account? <a class="login-link" id="login-link" ui-sref="login">Log in</a>
    </p>
  </form>
</div><!--//form-container-->
```

app.js

```
angular
  .module('mainApp', [
    'services.config',
    'mainApp.signup'
  ])
  .config(['$urlRouterProvider', function($urlRouterProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

  }])
```

signup.js

```
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc function
 * @name mainApp.signup
 * @description
 * # SignupCtrl
 */
 angular
 .module('mainApp.signup', [
  'ui.router',
  'angular-storage'
  ])
 .config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider){
  $stateProvider.state('signup',{
    url: '/signup',
    controller: 'SignupCtrl',
    views: {
      'header': {
        templateUrl: '/pages/templates/nav.html'
      },
      'content' : {
        templateUrl: '/pages/signup/signup.html'
      },
      'footer' : {
        templateUrl: '/pages/templates/footer.html'
      }
    }
  });
}])
.controller( 'SignupCtrl', function SignupController( $scope, $http, store, $state) {

  $scope.user = {};

  $scope.createUser = function() {
    $http({
      url: 'http://localhost:3001/users',
      method: 'POST',
      data: $scope.user
    }).then(function(response) {
      store.set('jwt', response.data.id_token);
      $state.go('home');
    }, function(error) {
      alert(error.data);
    });
  }

});
```

Comment: The controller will be bound to the `ui-view` directive. [ui-view](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-view). Do you have that in your index.html? Your 'signup' config seems to miss also the template or templateUrl property.

Comment: just updated index.html.  templateUrl is under views

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/q4CS3ypCyrEG5cMEyPfM?p=preview). Firstly, check this Q & A:

[Are there different ways of declaring the controller associated with an Angular UI Router state](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29922718/1679310)

Where we can see, that

> controller does **not** belong to `state`. It belongs to `view`!

This should be the state definition:

```
$stateProvider.state('signup',{
    url: '/signup',
    //controller: 'SignupCtrl',
    views: {
      'header': {
        templateUrl: 'pages/templates/nav.html'
      },
      'content' : {
        templateUrl: 'pages/signup/signup.html',
        controller: 'SignupCtrl',
      },
      'footer' : {
        templateUrl: 'pages/templates/footer.html'
      }
    }
});
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/q4CS3ypCyrEG5cMEyPfM?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You need a template to bind a controller.

In the docs [ui-router Controllers](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki)

> Controllers
>
> You can assign a controller to your template. Warning: The controller
>   will not be instantiated if template is not defined.

Comment: I now added template: ..., will that help? I don't see any change

Comment: I think you also need a `ui-view` directive in the index/parent.html to bind the template with its controller.