# UI-Router will not resolve $http call

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-service

I have a api that i want to resolve name for "bubble". This i would like to inject into controller - but problem is that i have tried different approaches and all just say...undefined and some injection problems... :(

Code:

```
.state('bubbles', {
    abstract: false,
    url: "/bubbles/:bubbleId/feed",
    controller: 'BubblesController',
    data: {
        authorizedRoles: [USER_ROLES.editor]
    },
    resolve: {
        resolvedBubbleName: function ($http, $stateParams) {
            var url = 'https://XXXXXXX.net/api/Bubble/11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111';
            return $http.get(url)
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log('response ' + response);
                return response;
            });
        },
        views: {
            'navigation': {
                templateUrl: "/raqt/shared/partials/navigation.html"
            },
            'main': {
                templateUrl: "/raqt/bubbles/partials/bubbles.html"
                //controller: function ($scope, resolvedBubbleName) {
                //    $scope.resolvedBubbleName = resolvedBubbleName; 
                //  // resolvedBubbleName is always undefined, i.e.,
                //  //  UI router is not injecting it
                //}

            }
        },
    }

})
```

In my controller i tried different approaches and this that i think should work... gives error injection...

```
BubblesController.$inject = ['$stateParams', '$state', '$log', '$timeout', '$interval', '$scope', 'BubblesService', 'CONFIG', '$http', 'resolvedBubbleName'];

function BubblesController($stateParams, $state, $log, $timeout, $interval, $scope, BubblesService, CONFIG, $http, resolvedBubbleName) {
    $scope.title = 'bubbles-controller';
    alert(resolvedBubbleName);
    $scope.bubbleId = $state.params.bubbleId;
```

Error from page

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: resolvedBubbleNameProvider <- resolvedBubbleName <- BubblesController
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/unpr?p0=resolvedBubbleNameProvider%20%3C-%20resolvedBubbleName%20%3C-%20BubblesController
    at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (http://localhost:3604/js/lib/angular/angular.js:63:12)
    at http://localhost:3604/js/lib/angular/angular.js:4015:19
    at Object.getService [as get] (http://localhost:3604/js/lib/angular/angular.js:4162:39)
    at http://localhost:3604/js/lib/angular/angular.js:4020:45
    at getService (http://localhost:3604/js/lib/angular/angular.js:4162:39)
    at Object.invoke (http://localhost:3604/js/lib/angular/angular.js:4194:13)
    at $get.extend.instance (http://localhost:3604/js/lib/angular/angular.js:8493:21)
    at http://localhost:3604/js/lib/angular/angular.js:7739:13
    at forEach (http://localhost:3604/js/lib/angular/angular.js:331:20)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:3604/js/lib/angular/angular.js:7738:11) <div ui-view="main" class="ng-scope">
```

I can see that $http call is having data and i know controller works well otherwise - but this resolve driving me mad.. :(

***I will be off for couple of hours - but i WILL ge back to this if you see some problems in my code i will ge back and answer!... :)***

Answer (score 0):

I would say, that you've wrongly nested **`views : {}`** into the **`resolve : {}`**. There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XgLvHYNoyRGSf0C7VhUK?p=preview)

I just moved your definitions into correct positions and it is working

```
.state('bubbles', {
    abstract: false,
    url: "/bubbles/:bubbleId/feed",
    //controller: 'BubblesController',
    data: {
      authorizedRoles: [{}], //USER_ROLES.editor]
    },
    resolve: {
      resolvedBubbleName: ['$http', '$stateParams',
        function($http, $stateParams) {
          //var url = 'https://XXXXXXX.net/api/Bubble/11111111-1111-1...';
          var url = 'someData.json'
          return $http.get(url)
            .then(function(response) {
              console.log('response ' + response);
              return response.data;
            });
        }
      ],
    },
    views: {
      'navigation': {
        templateUrl: "raqt/shared/partials/navigation.html",
        controller: 'BubblesController',
      },
      'main': {
        templateUrl: "raqt/bubbles/partials/bubbles.html",
        controller: ['$scope', 'resolvedBubbleName',
          function($scope, resolvedBubbleName) {
            $scope.resolvedBubbleName = resolvedBubbleName; 
          }
        ]
      }
    },
})
```

Also, one very important note:

> `controller` belongs to **view** - **not** to *state*

You can read more here:

- [Are there different ways of declaring the controller associated with an Angular UI Router state](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29922718/1679310)

Check the working example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/XgLvHYNoyRGSf0C7VhUK?p=preview)

EXTEND

In case, that we adjusted all the code as above and we are provided with this error:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: resolvedBubbleNameProvider <- resolvedBubbleName <- BubblesController

We are most likely in one of these scenarios:

- we have elsewhere in our state hierarchy reused the **`"BubblesController"`**, while not having **`resolve : { 'resolvedBubbleName': ... }`** in place
- we declared somewhere **`ng-controller="BubblesController"`** - which is not managed by UI-Router. And it does not have access to so called **`locals`** (containing resolved values)

so, be sure where is the controller defined - all will start working then...

Comment: Hi sorry for late reply. I tried and look at your code and looked at mine - and your is working BUT i still get very weird message that inject is wrong.
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: resolvedBubbleNameProvider <- resolvedBubbleName <- BubblesController
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/unpr?p0=  :(

Comment: I extended my answer, with 2 more suspected scenarios. Hope that will help and work for you ;)

Comment: WELL - this is so embarrasing - I using grunt and watcher for files and minification.... and now i guess you know what happend... I been editing wrong file because grunt wasnt watching that file correctly! 

I will be testning you solution this afternoon when i get back home again..  im pretty sure this will work! :)

Comment: Hope it will.. wish you make it! Angular and UI-Router are real diamonds ;) Good luck